# Error opening output encoder when trying to merge images with resizing and a fade transition in FFmpeg

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I running into an issue when trying to merge images with resizing and a fade transition, but I am running into an error for the output encoder.

The command I am currently trying --

```
ffmpeg \ 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/action-21892_1920.png \ 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/alex-wong-17992.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/alligator-2501474_1920.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v0]; \
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v1]; \
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v2]; \
[3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v3]; \
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[v]" -f mp4 -c:v libx264 -map "[v]" \
-r 25 -y /path/to/output-4803.mp4 2>&1
```

Console error --

```
ffmpeg version N-90767-g768c077-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
  libavutil      56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 18.100 /  7. 18.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from '/path/to/action-21892_1920.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1279, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x2063e80] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 4177x2774, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x2066100] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #2, png_pipe, from '/path/to/alex-wong-17992.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 5745x3830, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x2a5b0c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #3, png_pipe, from '/path/to/alligator-2501474_1920.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1280, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> setpts
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> setpts
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> setpts
  Stream #3:0 (png) -> setpts
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
[libx264 @ 0x2a5f1c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2a5f1c0] using cpu capabilities: none!
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

I've tried multiple options and nothing seems to work, and I keep getting the same message. Any ideas where I'm messing up at?

**UPDATE**

After trying @Gyan suggestion, this is the output I see in the console --

```
ffmpeg version N-90767-g768c077-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
  libavutil      56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 18.100 /  7. 18.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from '/path/to/action-21892_1920.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1279, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x239fe80] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 4177x2774, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x23a2100] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #2, png_pipe, from '/path/to/alex-wong-17992.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 5745x3830, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[png_pipe @ 0x2d970c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #3, png_pipe, from '/path/to/alligator-2501474_1920.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1280, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> setpts
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> setpts
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> setpts
  Stream #3:0 (png) -> setpts
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (wrapped_avframe)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
Output #0, null, to '/path/to/output-4803.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.13.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: wrapped_avframe, rgb24, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.19.100 wrapped_avframe
frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=N/A speed=0.00542x    
frame=    5 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0131x    
frame=    8 fps=0.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.32 bitrate=N/A speed=0.02x    
frame=   11 fps=0.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0263x    
frame=   14 fps=0.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0322x    
frame=   17 fps=0.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0376x    
frame=   28 fps=1.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0601x    
frame=   45 fps=2.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.094x    
frame=   66 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.134x    
frame=   88 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.175x    
frame=  107 fps=5.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.207x    
frame=  119 fps=5.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.224x    
[png @ 0x392d880] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x392d880] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  128 fps=5.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.227x    
frame=  129 fps=5.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.16 bitrate=N/A speed=0.219x    
frame=  130 fps=5.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.20 bitrate=N/A speed=0.211x    
frame=  131 fps=5.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.204x    
frame=  132 fps=4.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.197x    
frame=  133 fps=4.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.32 bitrate=N/A speed=0.191x    
frame=  134 fps=4.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.36 bitrate=N/A speed=0.185x    
frame=  135 fps=4.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.40 bitrate=N/A speed=0.18x    
frame=  136 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.175x    
frame=  137 fps=4.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=N/A speed=0.171x    
frame=  138 fps=4.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.166x    
frame=  139 fps=4.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.163x    
frame=  140 fps=4.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.60 bitrate=N/A speed=0.159x    
frame=  141 fps=3.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.156x    
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  141 fps=3.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.151x    
[png @ 0x392eac0] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x392eac0] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  143 fps=3.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.15x    
frame=  147 fps=3.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.92 bitrate=N/A speed=0.152x    
frame=  152 fps=3.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.155x    
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x3930380] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3930380] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  159 fps=4.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.161x    
frame=  167 fps=4.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.167x    
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x3931bc0] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3931bc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  175 fps=4.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.174x    
frame=  183 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.179x    
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x3933480] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3933480] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  191 fps=4.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.185x    
frame=  199 fps=4.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.19x    
frame=  205 fps=4.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.36 bitrate=N/A speed=0.193x    
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x3934cc0] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3934cc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  211 fps=4.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.198x    
/path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 4 times
frame=  219 fps=4.9 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.202x    
/path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 2 times
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Cannot allocate memory
/path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=  225 fps=5.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.206x    
/path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=  228 fps=5.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.36 bitrate=N/A speed=0.206x    
[png @ 0x3948240] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3948240] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  231 fps=4.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.48 bitrate=N/A speed=0.195x    
frame=  232 fps=4.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.187x    
frame=  233 fps=4.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.18x    
frame=  234 fps=4.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.60 bitrate=N/A speed=0.173x    
frame=  235 fps=4.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.168x    
frame=  236 fps=4.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.163x    
frame=  237 fps=3.8 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.72 bitrate=N/A speed=0.158x    
frame=  238 fps=3.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.76 bitrate=N/A speed=0.153x    
frame=  239 fps=3.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.149x    
frame=  240 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.84 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  241 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.88 bitrate=N/A speed=0.142x    
frame=  242 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.92 bitrate=N/A speed=0.138x    
frame=  243 fps=3.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:09.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.135x    
frame=  244 fps=3.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.132x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  244 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.128x    
[png @ 0x3949480] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3949480] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  246 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.126x    
frame=  248 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.20 bitrate=N/A speed=0.126x    
frame=  250 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.126x    
frame=  253 fps=3.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.40 bitrate=N/A speed=0.124x    
frame=  256 fps=3.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.52 bitrate=N/A speed=0.124x    
frame=  260 fps=3.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.125x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x394ad40] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x394ad40] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  263 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.84 bitrate=N/A speed=0.126x    
frame=  266 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:10.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.127x    
frame=  270 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.12 bitrate=N/A speed=0.128x    
frame=  274 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.28 bitrate=N/A speed=0.129x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  276 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.36 bitrate=N/A speed=0.129x    
[png @ 0x394c580] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x394c580] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  280 fps=3.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.13x    
frame=  283 fps=3.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.68 bitrate=N/A speed=0.13x    
frame=  287 fps=3.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:11.84 bitrate=N/A speed=0.131x    
frame=  291 fps=3.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.132x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x394de40] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x394de40] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  295 fps=3.2 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.20 bitrate=N/A speed=0.133x    
frame=  300 fps=3.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.40 bitrate=N/A speed=0.135x    
frame=  305 fps=3.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.60 bitrate=N/A speed=0.136x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x394f680] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x394f680] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  310 fps=3.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:12.84 bitrate=N/A speed=0.138x    
frame=  315 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.139x    
frame=  320 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.24 bitrate=N/A speed=0.14x    
frame=  324 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.40 bitrate=N/A speed=0.141x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
[png @ 0x3950f40] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3950f40] thread_get_buffer() failed
frame=  328 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.60 bitrate=N/A speed=0.142x    
frame=  331 fps=3.4 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.72 bitrate=N/A speed=0.142x    
frame=  335 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:13.88 bitrate=N/A speed=0.143x    
frame=  338 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.143x    
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Cannot allocate memory
frame=  340 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.08 bitrate=N/A speed=0.143x    
[png @ 0x3952780] get_buffer() failed
[png @ 0x3952780] thread_get_buffer() failed
/path/to/alex-wong-17992.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=  345 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.32 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
/path/to/alex-wong-17992.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=  349 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.48 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  351 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  353 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.64 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  355 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.72 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  357 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.80 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  359 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.88 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  361 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:14.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  363 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.145x    
frame=  373 fps=3.6 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:15.44 bitrate=N/A speed=0.148x    
/path/to/alligator-2501474_1920.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 4 times
frame=  391 fps=3.7 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:16.16 bitrate=N/A speed=0.154x    
/path/to/alligator-2501474_1920.png: Cannot allocate memory
    Last message repeated 10 times
frame=  401 fps=3.8 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:16.56 bitrate=N/A speed=0.157x    
video:210kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: If you change to `-f null -map "[v]" -r 25 -y -  2>&1`. does the encoding proceed?

Comment: @Gyan Ok i tried it and updated my question with the error it gave.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get things working by first going to my CLI and doing `yum search x264` and then updating/installing ALL x264 related files.

Then the command I used for ffmpeg is -

```
ffmpeg \
-threads 1 \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/action-21892_1920.png \ 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/agriculture-colors-countryside-1253748.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/alex-wong-17992.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i /path/to/alligator-2501474_1920.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v0]; \
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v1]; \
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v2]; \
[3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9[v3]; \
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[v]" -c:v libx264 -map "[v]" \ 
-r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -y output.mp4 2>&1
```